# Best way to return a nested object the matches a property requested

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm trying to create a new object that only contains the a product array with the seller I req.  I have an order object that has a product array. I'd like to return a specific seller. I tried:

```
const newOrders = orders.map((element) => {
        return {
          ...element,
          product: element.product.filter(
            (seller) => seller === req.currentUser!.id
          ),
        };
      });
```

does mongoose have a preferred method for doing what I bring to achieve? I've read through the find queries but none of the methods seem useful to this use case.

```
orders: [

{
userId: "638795ad742ef7a17e258693",
status: "pending",
shippingInfo: {
line1: "599 East Liberty Street",
line2: null,
city: "Toronto",
country: "CA",
postal_code: "M7K 8P3",
state: "MT"
},
product: [
{
title: "new image",
description: "a log description",
seller: "6369589f375b5196f62e3675",
__v: 1,
id: "63737e4b0adf387c5e863d33"
},
{
title: "Mekks",
description: "Ple",
seller: "6369589f375b5196f62e3675",
__v: 1,
id: "6376706808cf1adafd5af32f"
},
{
title: "Meeks Prodyuct",
description: "long description",
seller: "63868795a6196afbc3677cfe",
__v: 1,
id: "63868812a6196afbc3677d06"
}
],
version: 1,
id: "6388138170892249e01bdcba"
}
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Im sure this can be improved, doesn't feel that its the best way possible but it gets the result. Like the previous answer you have to find first the order the seller is in then find the products than filter the seller by the id. I'm using typescript and there's a bug https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50769 so you have to use the bracket notation.

```
  const orders = await Order.find({
    "product.seller": req.currentUser!.id,
   });

  const allOrders = orders[0].product;

  const sellerOrders = allOrders.filter((obj) => {
    return obj["seller"] === req.currentUser!.id;
   });
```